# Create file with matched and non-matched records using Pig script

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Can you please suggest on below file matching logic and removing duplicate entries using Pig -

**1) Removing duplicate entries based on key RoleId-**

```
InputFile1
--------------
RoleId   Name 
1        A 
2        B 
3        C
2        D 
5        E
5        F
7        G
```

### OutpufFile1 (Only unique records)

```
RoleId   Name 
1        A 
3        C
7        G
```

### OutpufFile2 (Capture duplicate records)

```
RoleId   Name 
2        B
2        D
5        E
5        F
```

**2) File Matching key is RoleId -**

```
InputFile1  InputFile2 
----------- ---------- 
RoleId Name RoleId Age 
1      A    1      20 
2      B    2      21 
3      C    1      22 
4      D    2      23 
5      E    3      24 
            7      25
```

**OutpufFile1 (Matching records) OutputFile2 (Un-matching from 1st)**

```
--------------------           ----------- 

    RoleId Name Age                RoleId Name 
    1      A    20, 22             4      D 
    2      B    21, 23             5      E
    3      C    24
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below approach?

**Problem1 Solution:**
**input**

```
1       A
2       B
3       C
2       D
5       E
5       F
7       G
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'in.txt' USING PigStorage() AS(RoleId:int,Name:chararray);
B = GROUP A BY RoleId;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE FLATTEN($1) AS(RoleId,Name),COUNT(A) AS cnt;

SPLIT C INTO Distval IF (cnt==1), NonDistVal IF (cnt>=2);

D = FOREACH Distval GENERATE RoleId,Name;
STORE D INTO 'DistFile' USING PigStorage();

E = FOREACH NonDistVal GENERATE RoleId,Name;
STORE E INTO 'NonDistFile' USING PigStorage();
```

**Output:**
cat DistFile/part-r-00000

```
1       A
3       C
7       G
```

cat NonDistFile/part-r-00000

```
2       B
2       D
5       E
5       F
```

**Problem2 Solution:**
**InputFile1**

```
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       E
```

**InputFile2**

```
1       20
2       21
1       22
2       23
3       24
7       25
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'InputFile1' USING PigStorage() AS(RoleId:long, Name:chararray);
B = LOAD 'InputFile2' USING PigStorage() AS(RoleId:long, Age:int);

C = COGROUP A BY RoleId ,B BY RoleId;
D = FILTER C BY NOT IsEmpty(A);

SPLIT D INTO RoleMatch IF NOT IsEmpty(B),NoRoleMatch IF IsEmpty(B);


E = FOREACH RoleMatch GENERATE FLATTEN($1),BagToTuple(B.Age);
STORE E INTO 'RoleMatchFile' USING PigStorage();


F = FOREACH NoRoleMatch GENERATE FLATTEN($1);
STORE F  INTO 'NoRoleMatchFile' USING PigStorage();
```

**Output:**
cat RoleMatchFile/part-r-00000

```
1       A       (20,22)
2       B       (21,23)
3       C       (24)
```

cat NoRoleMatchFile/part-r-00000

```
4       D
5       E
```